# Хранение данных о предметах (массовый вариант)

Tags: c++, ооп, разработка-игр, хранение-данных

Пишу игру а-ля песочница. Конечно, в игре есть много разных предметов. Мне нужно написать гибкую систему, чтобы можно было добавить какой-то предмет без перекомпиляции. Как хранить данные о их шаблонах (имя, параметры, пути к изображениям)?

P.S. В игре есть поддержка Lua скриптов (если это важно)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Архитектура хранения данных - сложная штука. Ведь помимо хранения в памяти, нужно ещё и хранение в оффлайне.

Классический способ - вынести базовые поля в один тип, и оставить поле под дополнительные параметры. Например, так:

```
struct Param {
    enum class Type : uint8_t {
        EMPTY = 0,
        INTEGER,
        DOUBLE,
        BOOLEAN,
        STRING,
        ARRAY,
        DICTIONARY,
    } _type;

    union {
        int64_t intVal;
        double doubleVal;
        bool boolVal;
        string * strVal;
        vector<Param> * arrayVal;
        map<string, Param> * dictVal;
    };
}

struct ItemClass {
    string name;
    string image;
    // другие общие параметры

    map<string, Param> custom;
}
```

Comment: Хм... Интересный способ. Спасибо.